# What's the meaning of まだ知り合ったばっかりだ?

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-ばかり

> 「使徒になってもらったけど、私はアヴァロのことまだ全然知らないなぁって思って」
>   「そうだなぁ。まだ知り合ったばっかりだし仕方ないんじゃないか？」

These are some lines from a game I'm currently playing. Does the second line mean "There's still a lot to find out about each other[...]", まだ知り合った being an implicit negative? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this up into parts. The whole clause:

> まだ知り合ったばっかりだし

> 知り合った

means "we met/made each other's acquaintance".

> 知り合ったばっかりだ

Adding ばっかり to a verb in past tense means it just happened. So this means "only just met" (plus the copula だ).

> まだ知り合ったばっかりだ

まだ means "still." We've still only just met. (This is hard to translate directly into English, but it intensifies the ばっかり. まだ知り合った by itself doesn't make sense.)

Finally, the particle し just means, "and/so". I would translate the whole sentence as follows:

> I mean, we've only just met, so what are you gonna do, right?

There's no negative in this sentence.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks for the detailed breakdown :)